# Are there Dart engines for C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, dart

I know it just released, but are there any Dart engines for C/++ like SpiderMonkey for Javascript, or the JNI for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dart SDK comes with a Dart VM that is written in C++. It can be used as a standalone program, or can be embedded in other programs (like, for instance, Chromium).